# To implement the following swift code in objective-c?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, webview

I am implementing the web view through `react-native`. Therefore, I use the `react-native-webview` library. However, "window.open" and "window.close" are not implemented in the `react-native-webview`.

I need to apply that part of the code for `social login`. So I found the `swift` code document. However, I don't know how to change this document to an `objective-c` code.

[object-c partial code of react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebView.m#L310-L316)

- swift document

```swift
 // webView list management
 var webViews = [WKWebView]()
 ...
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
                 for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                 windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures
    ) -> WKWebView? {
        guard let frame = self.webViews.last?.frame else {
            return nil
        }

        //Creating and returning a web view creates a parent relationship with the current web view.
        return createWebView(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
    }

    /// ---------- popup close ----------
    func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        destroyCurrentWebView()
    }

    // Examples of Web View Generation Methods
    func createWebView(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
        
        // set delegate
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
                
        // add view
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        self.webViews.append(webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    // Examples of webview deletion methods
    func destroyCurrentWebView() {
        // remove from webview lists and screens
        self.webViews.popLast()?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

How can I apply this code to suit the `react-native-webview`?

### EDIT

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
  if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
    [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
  }
  WKWebView *popUpWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: navigationAction.targetFrame configuration: configuration];
  popUpWebView.uiDelegate = self;
  popUpWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
  [_webView addSubview:popUpWebView];
  return nil;
}

- (void)webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView {
  [_webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I looked at the document and changed it as follows. However, an error occurs when building. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you just want to convert the code snippet in your question to Obj C or something else ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank The purpose is correct. However, the code must be correct for the react-native-webview. Therefore, I attached a link to the react-native-webview code.

Comment: I cannot be sure of react native as I don't develop for it, but I might be able to help with converting to obj-c

Comment: @ShawnFrank Enough! I have attached the source link of the react-native-webview so that I can set the criteria for the conversion. I think you can fill it out based on that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, I am not sure if this will work for React Native but this Obj-C code is the same as your swift code and should compile

**In your .h file**

Your `.h` file will probably need to be the same as [RNCWebView.h](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebView.h) and you might need to remove anything unwanted / unused

**In your .m file**

Similarly, your `.m` will be similar to [RNCWebView.m](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebView.m) and remove what you don't use.

Then as per your swift code, these are the updated Obj C versions of those functions

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration
   forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
        windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
    
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    }
    
    if ([webViews count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    WKWebView *currentWebView = [webViews lastObject];
    
    WKWebView *popUpWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: currentWebView.frame
                                                 configuration: configuration];
    
    popUpWebView.UIDelegate = self;
    popUpWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [webView addSubview:popUpWebView];
    
    return popUpWebView;
}

- (void)webViewDidClose:(WKWebView *)webView
{
  [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Update**

If the `webViews` variable from the original swift code is unused / not needed, you probably need to update the `webView createWebViewWithConfiguration` as follows:

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration
   forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction
        windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
    
    if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
        [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
    }
    
    WKWebView *popUpWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: webView.bounds
                                                 configuration: configuration];
    
    popUpWebView.UIDelegate = self;
    popUpWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
    [webView addSubview:popUpWebView];
    
    return popUpWebView;
}
```

Finally, just to clarify:

- The header does not need to be the same as mine, I just gave you an example if you were subclassing a UIViewController. You probably need to follow the header and implementation file defined [here](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebView.h)
- My goal was to convert your swift code into Obj C code that would compile, I cannot say if it is right for React Native however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a document that the article has webviews, but they are not actually used, so I didn't use them for my question. Is there any practical use?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebView.h

Comment: And I attached the link to the existing header file. Is it correct to write it at the top like the answer?

Comment: @hongdeveloper - I only kept `webViews` because it was part of your original Swift code. If you are not using it, then it is not needed and then it will also give us the wrong frame. I have made a small update if you don't need to use `webViews`.

Comment: @hongdeveloper - The header that I created does not need to be the same. I just gave an example as if you were creating a UIViewController subclass. In swift, this is `class YourVC: UIViewController`, maybe you should so you should change this accordingly. If you are not using `webViews`, I made a small update for that. However, I cannot really help with react native, I can only help if you need to convert Swift to Obj C.

Comment: Although the "ViewController.h" file does not exist in the react-native-webview and cannot be used, I think it is the correct code to answer the question, so I will use it as an answer.